# GraphQL type containing a finite set of string values

Tags: graphql

In typescript I can write:

```
type T = 'some words' | 'some other words' | ...
```

Is it possible to define such a type in GraphQL schema?

I have a downstream service that returns a set of values, some containing blanks and I would like to have a type restricted to only those values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a [custom scalar](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/schema/custom-scalars/) that only allows your set of values.

In the absence of spaces you could also use an enum.

Comment: Thanks Michael. That's what I expected, but it's disappointing. For this purpose that's little better than just using String. I was hoping to write GraphQL schema that would result in the generation of the desired typescript type.